# how to pass childname and parentid in Url using anchor tag(.xslt)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, xslt

This is my .xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<BlogCategories>
  <BlogCategory ID="1" ParentID="0" Name="Travel" Active="1" seo_keywords="Travel Blogs" seo_description="Travel Blogs" ParentName=""/>
  <BlogCategory ID="2" ParentID="0" Name="HealthCare" Active="1" seo_keywords="HealthCare  Blogs" seo_description="HealthCare  Blogs" ParentName=""/>
<BlogCategory ID="13" ParentID="1" Name="Destinations" Active="1" seo_keywords="Destinations" seo_description="Destinations" ParentName="Travel"/>
  <BlogCategory ID="14" ParentID="1" Name="Stories " Active="1" seo_keywords="Stories " seo_description="Stories " ParentName="Travel"/>
  <Parent Id="1" ParentName="Travel"/>
    <Parent Id="2" ParentName="HealthCare"/>
</BlogCategories>
```

This is my .xslt code:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Parent">
               <div class="grid-col-3">
                 <ul>
                   <h4><a href="ParentName/Id">
                     <xsl:value-of select="@ParentName"></xsl:value-of>
                   </a></h4>
                   <xsl:for-each select="/BlogCategories/BlogCategory[@ParentID = current()/@Id]">
                     <!--<xsl:if test="@ParentID=$Id">-->
                     <li class="lis">
                       <a href="">
                         <xsl:value-of select="@Name"></xsl:value-of>
                       </a>
                     </li>
                     <!--</xsl:if>-->
                   </xsl:for-each>
                 </ul>
               </div>
             </xsl:for-each>
```

I want to send the url in href here <`h4><a href="ParentName/Id">`
example:Suppose if i click on healthcare then the url must be `.../healthcare/1`

just like
If i click on Destinations then the url like `.../Destinations/13`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax I think you are looking for is this....

```
<a href="{@ParentName}/{@Id}">
```

The curly braces are known as [Attribute Value Templates](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates), and represent an expression to be evaluated, rather than output literally. So `{@ParentName}` will be replaced with the value of the `ParentName` attribute, and similarly of `{@Id}`.

Where you have `<a href="">` you therefore probably need this

```
<a href="../{@Name}/{@ID}">
```

As an aside, do note that XML and XSLT are case-sensitive, so `Id` is not the same as `ID`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xsl:element`, `xsl:attribute` and `concat` like this:

```
<xsl:element name="a">
   <xsl:attribute name="href">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(ParentName,'/',Id)"/>"/>
   </xsl:attribute>
   <xsl:value-of select="ParentName"/>
</xsl:element>
```

`ParentName`, `Id` should be value of a selected node or selected attribute in xml code.